# More than one indexes on same column in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, non-clustered-index

If we create one more non-clustered index on a column which already have one in SQL server, what Would be the effect of that?

Comment: Yes you can do it. But whats the purpose of it and how are you defining it? Creating two identical indexes on one column is basically a waste of space as you are storing (and maintaining) the same information twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. But either more indexes on a column or the use of a non-clustered index in a table may decrease the performance.

The effect is judged at runtime based on your search condition.

http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/duplicate-indexes-and-sql-server-performance-nh01/#.VWP8JUaWvQA

[SQL Server: multiple index for the same columns performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943199/sql-server-multiple-index-for-the-same-columns-performance)

[Create more than one non clustered index on same column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477252/create-more-than-one-non-clustered-index-on-same-column-in-sql-server)

[SQL Server creating multiple nonclustered indexes for one column vs having multiple columns in just one index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037644/sql-server-creating-multiple-nonclustered-indexes-for-one-column-vs-having-multi)